# Converted a nested JSON column to Pyspark DataFrame Columns

Tags: arrays, json, dataframe, pyspark

I have read and stored parquet files in S3 using pyspark.pandas dataframes. Now in the second phase I am trying to read the parquet files in a pyspark dataframe in databricks, and I facing issues converting the nested json columns into proper columns. First I read the parquet data from S3 using the command:

```
adf = spark.read.parquet('s3://path')
```

An example nested column in my pyspark dataframe looks like this:

```
event_params:array
   element:struct
      key:string
      value:struct
          double_value:double
          float_value:integer
          int_value:long
          string_value:string
```

Example Data in a pyspark dataframe column:

```
0: {"key": "ignore_referrer", "value": {"double_value": null, "float_value": null, "int_value": null, "string_value": "true"}}
1: {"key": "session_engaged", "value": {"double_value": null, "float_value": null, "int_value": null, "string_value": "1"}}
2: {"key": "engagement_time_msec", "value": {"double_value": null, "float_value": null, "int_value": 123, "string_value": null}}
3: {"key": "value", "value": {"double_value": null, "float_value": null, "int_value": 23, "string_value": null}}
4: {"key": "page_location", "value": {"double_value": null, "float_value": null, "int_value": null, "string_value": "https://abc/0.0.23-manual/index.html"}}
```

I am trying to create new columns for all the fields present in the json, so for example the result I am looking for is something like this:

```
key  session_engaged value 
1        12           true
```

One way I tried was using spark.sql, but I am getting errors like Dataframe has no object'_get_object_id':

bdf = adf.createOrReplaceTempView(adf)

```
df = spark.sql('''
SELECT
               event_timestamp,
               event_name,
               event_params :element:value
 FROM bdf;''')
```

**ERROR:**

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

I have tried using spark.SQL to do this, and I have also explored the explode function, but these columns are different for each row, and I want to just convert all these json nested structures to columns. If anybody can point me in the right direction using any working approach that would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about the expected output, where did 12 come from?
You can use `posexplode` to get every element in `event_params` in a row with the position as a column of its own.

Then you can access all json fields with `.select("*", col("col.value.*"))` and this command will add the json fields to the df.

full code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import posexplode, col


df \
.select(posexplode("event_params")) \
.select("*", col("col.key") , col("col.value.*")) \
.show(truncate=False)
```